# When there is dependency between several .java files, do we need to compile them in some order?

Tags: java, javac

When compiling several .java files with some dependency relation between them, do we need to compile them in some order?

Must a dependency be .class file? Or can a dependency be a .java file?

Specifically, when A.java depends on B.class file compiled from B.java file, but B.class hasn't been created (i.e. B.java file hasn't been compiled into B.class), can we compile A.java by specifying the directory for B.java in `java -cp`? Or do we need to compile B.java into B.class first, and then specify the directory for B.class in `java -cp` when compiling A.java?

For example, from https://dzone.com/articles/java-8-how-to-create-executable-fatjar-without-ide, `./src/main/java/com/exec/one/Main.java` depends on `./src/main/java/com/exec/one/service/MagicService.java`, and both haven't been compiled yet.

Why does the following compilation fail?

```
$ javac  ./src/main/java/com/exec/one/*.java -d ./out/
./src/main/java/com/exec/one/Main.java:3: error: package com.exec.one.service does not exist
import com.exec.one.service.MagicService;
                           ^
./src/main/java/com/exec/one/Main.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
        MagicService service = new MagicService();
        ^
  symbol:   class MagicService
  location: class Main
./src/main/java/com/exec/one/Main.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
        MagicService service = new MagicService();
                                   ^
  symbol:   class MagicService
  location: class Main
3 errors
```

Why does the following compilation succeed? How can one compile them in one `javac` command? How is `-cp ./src/main/java` used in the compilation? What happens in the compilation process?

```
$ javac -cp ./src/main/java ./src/main/java/com/exec/one/*.java ./src/main/java/com/exec/one/**/*.java
```

---

./src/main/java/com/exec/one/Main.java

```
package com.exec.one;                                                                                                                                                                  

import com.exec.one.service.MagicService;                                                                                                                                              

public class Main {                                                                                                                                                                    

    public static void main(String[] args){                                                                                                                                            

        System.out.println("Main Class Start");                                                                                                                                        

        MagicService service = new MagicService();                                                                                                                                     

        System.out.println("MESSAGE : " + service.getMessage());                                                                                                                       

     }                                                                                                                                                                                  

}
```

./src/main/java/com/exec/one/service/MagicService.java

```
package com.exec.one.service;                                                                                                                                                          

public class MagicService {                                                                                                                                                            

  private final String message;                                                                                                                                                      

    public MagicService(){                                                                                                                                                             

        this.message = "Magic Message";                                                                                                                                                

    }                                                                                                                                                                                  

    public String getMessage(){                                                                                                                                                        

         return message;                                                                                                                                                                

    }                                                                                                                                                                                  

}
```

Comment: Is this a maven project?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen It is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*TL;DR* As documented below, if you compile with this simpler command, where you only ask to compile the `Main` class, the compiler will still locate and compile the required `MagicService` class, because it can find the source file on the classpath.

```
javac -cp ./src/main/java ./src/main/java/com/exec/one/Main.java
```

---

See the ["Searching for Types" section](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#BHCJJJAJ) of the compiler documentation page.

Quoting it all here for your convenience, with highlights (**bold** and/or *italic*) added by me:

> To compile a source file, the compiler often needs information about a type, but the type definition is not in the source files specified on the command line. The compiler needs type information for every class or interface used, extended, or implemented in the source file. This includes classes and interfaces not explicitly mentioned in the source file, but that provide information through inheritance.
>
> For example, when you create a subclass `java.applet.Applet`, you are also using the ancestor classes of Applet: `java.awt.Panel`, `java.awt.Container`, `java.awt.Component`, and `java.lang.Object`.
>
> **When the compiler needs type information, it searches for a *source* file or *class* file** that defines the type. The **compiler searches for *class* files first** in the bootstrap and extension classes, then in the user class path (which by default is the current directory). The user class path is defined by setting the `CLASSPATH` environment variable or by using the `-classpath` option.
>
> If you set the `-sourcepath` option, then the compiler searches the indicated path for source files. Otherwise, the **compiler searches the user class path for both *class* files and *source* files.**
>
> You can specify different bootstrap or extension classes with the `-bootclasspath` and the `-extdirs` options. See [Cross-Compilation Options](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#BHCIJIEG).
>
> A successful type search may produce a class file, a source file, or both. If both are found, then you can use the `-Xprefer` option to instruct the compiler which to use. If `newer` is specified, then the compiler uses the newer of the two files. If `source` is specified, the compiler uses the source file. The default is `newer`.
>
> **If a type search finds a *source* file** for a required type, either by itself, or as a result of the setting for the `-Xprefer` option, then the compiler reads the source file to get the information it needs. **By default the compiler also compiles the source file.** You can use the `-implicit` option to specify the behavior. If `none` is specified, then no class files are generated for the source file. If `class` is specified, then class files are generated for the source file.
>
> The compiler might not discover the need for some type information until after annotation processing completes. When the type information is found in a source file and no `-implicit` option is specified, the compiler gives a warning that the file is being compiled without being subject to annotation processing. To disable the warning, either specify the file on the command line (so that it will be subject to annotation processing) or use the `-implicit` option to specify whether or not class files should be generated for such source files.

Comment: Note that that is the behavior of the Oracle compiler, and may not be the same for other compiler implementations.

Comment: Thanks. I am using openjdk

Answer (score 3):

> Why does the following compilation fail?
>
> ```
> $ javac ./src/main/java/com/exec/one/*.java -d ./out/
> ```

Because `Main.java` (the only file picked up in that command) makes use of a class called `com.exec.one.service.MagicService` that is not available on the classpath nor is one of the files being compiled.

> Why does the following compilation succeed?
>
> ```
> $ javac -cp ./src/main/java ./src/main/java/com/exec/one/*.java ./src/main/java/com/exec/one/**/*.java
> ```

Because `Main.java` makes use of a class called `com.exec.one.service.MagicService` that is also one of the files being compiled.

> How can one compile them in one `javac` command?

What you have is already one command. The `javac` program accepts a list of source files to compile

```
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
```

> How is `-cp ./src/main/java` used in the compilation?

It's used to set the classpath, ie. it includes class files that may be needed during compilation. In your example, it's useless.

However, if you had compiled `MagicService` separately and pointed the `-cp` to wherever the corresponding `MagicServe.class` file was located (taking into account the directory structure that matches its containing package), it would have been useful. This is how 3rd party libraries are included in Java projects.

---

The Java compiler doesn't impose an ordering. Simply, at compilation time, all required classes must be available, either through a source file being compiled or a class available in the classpath.

Comment: Up-voted even though you are not entirely correct (see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55637269/5221149)). Source files may be compiled even if they are not listed in the command, as long as the source file is on the `sourcepath` (or `classpath` if no `sourcepath` is given).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you should start inside the path "/src/main/java". Only below that you have packages (com.exec.one) matching your folder names. So do a "cd src/main/java" and try:

```
javac ./com/exec/one/*.java
```